# How do you redirect input as out put with ReadLine and WriteLine? (Noob)

Tags: c#, input, output

i am trying to create a small game but i want the user to input his name so the game is a bit more realistic! how????
i am trying to make it so if you enter 3 (case 3) the application just closes!
This is the code!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Does anyone copy?");
           // Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("Is there anybody listening?");
           // Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("Please i need help!!!");
            //Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("1. Who is this?");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Yes i copy!");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Ignore the message!");
            String choice = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (choice)
            {
                case "1":
                    //Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine("I'm Emma!");
                    //Thread.Sleep(6000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Oh my God i tought nobody was going to answer!");
                    //Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Who are you?");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    //Thread.Sleep(6000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Oh my God i tought nobody was going to answer!");
                    //Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine("I'm Emma by the way!");
                    //Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Who are you?");
                    break;
                case "3":

                break;
            }

        Console.ReadLine();
        string yourName;
        yourName = Console.ReadLine();
        //Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("Hey {0}... Sorry i got you so worried... i was just scared someone was in my room!" yourName );
        //Thread.Sleep(20000);



    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a precise question? Does this code work? If not can you explain what is not working? Next time read the [help] and [ask]

Comment: how about putting breakpoints in your code, use the debugger, then check your logic and tell us what happens when you get to the switch case statement based on the 1st 2nd and 3rd thing the user types into the console window..? have you tried at least..?

Comment: If you want it to exit on `case "3"` then you either need to make it "fall through" to an exit point, or you can make case 3 do this: `Environment.Exit(0)`. Currently it falls through to `Console.ReadLine();` (above `string yourName;`), so it will not exit because it's waiting for an input.

Comment: we're not here to write code!!!! And why you talking like this!!???!!!? Seriously, at least put some effort into your question. We're not here to write your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are trying to use string.Format, the correct syntax would be:

```
string yourName;
yourName = Console.ReadLine();
//Thread.Sleep(10000);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Hey {0}... Sorry i got you so worried... i was just scared someone was in my room!", yourName));
//Thread.Sleep(20000);
```

The important part you are missing is this `Console.WriteLine(String.Format(`

You also need to separate your variable and the text with a comma, as they are different parameters in the `String.Format()` method.

Aside from this you could also use string interpolation like so

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hey {yourName}... Sorry i got you so worried... i was just scared someone was in my room!");
```

This works similarly to `String.Format`, but it is instead used by adding a `$` before the string.

A bonus of this is, as you can see, the variable name is inside the curly brackets - `{yourName}` as opposed to putting a 0. which is less code to write than in `String.Format`